# How to cache the application configs in memory in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, performance, caching, zend-framework2, configuration-files

One of the [must-haves](http://www.masterzendframework.com/reviews/maximising-zend-framework-2-performance-phpuk14/) for the performance optimization of a Zend Framework 2 application is the caching of the configurations. The idea is to merge them to one big config file (or actually two files, e.g. `module-classmap-cache.php` and `module-config-cache.php`), so that the config files don't need to be opened and merged on every request. (See the info in the [official documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html) and a how-to in the article of Rob Allen "[Caching your ZF2 merged configuration](https://akrabat.com/caching-your-zf2-merged-configuration/)"):

**`application.config.php`**

```
return [
    'modules' => [
        ...
    ],
    'module_listener_options' => [
        ...
        'config_cache_enabled' => true,
        'config_cache_key' => 'app_config',
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,
        'module_map_cache_key' => 'module_map',
        'cache_dir' => './data/cache',
    ],
];
```

I'd like to optimize it a bit more and load the configs from the in-memory cache (e.g. APCu). Is it provided by the framework? Or do I have to write a this functionality myself?

Answer (score 2):

The caching mechanism is implemented in the `ConfigListener` class of the `ModuleManager` (source of [write config](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/blob/master/src/Listener/ConfigListener.php#L146) & [read config](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/blob/master/src/Listener/ConfigListener.php#L70)).
As you can see there, the only supported caching method is writing the cached configuration to a file.

It is instantiated as a default in the `DefaultListenerAggregate` ([source](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/blob/master/src/Listener/DefaultListenerAggregate.php#L98)), which again is hard coded in the `ModuleManagerFactory` of the MVC module ([source](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Service/ModuleManagerFactory.php#L42)).

In order to replace this with your own logic, you would have to:

- Replace the `ConfigListener` with your own (or at least extend the respective parts)
- Change the `ModuleManagerFactory` to explicitly set your own `ConfigListener` on the `DefaultListenerAggregate` before it gets lazy-created.

While feasible, it don't think it is actually worth the effort. As the merged config file is a php file, it should get cached by the OpCache anyway. And the OpCache ultimately is an php-optimized in-memory cache. So I'd expect it to be even faster then any all-purpose in-memory store.